# Why the OuterHTML feature leads to an Error

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control

I have been trying to change the HTML code of a select tag in an HTML code but whenever I do that the

```
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
```

error occurs.This is the C# code:

```
 public void SetDefaultValue(string ControlID,string Value)
 {
HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
HtmlElement list = doc.GetElementById(ControlID);
list.OuterHTML+= Value;         
 }
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    htmlLoadWebbrowser1.SetDefaultValue("D8876943-5861-4D62-9249-C5FEF88219FA", "<SELECT id=\"D8876943-5861-4D62-9249-C5FEF88219FA\" multiple size=\"4\" name=\"drop1\"> <OPTION value=\"3\">item 3</OPTION></SELECT>");            
}
```

The function is supposed to change the code of an select tag in an HTML page,it receives the ID of the control by "controlID" and generates the inner code by "Value". I suspect that I need to call the function elsewhere,the problem is that I do not know where. Thank you.

Comment: Which line produces that error?

Comment: @JanDvorak:When I call it in Form load the error is produced,but when I call it in a button,the program runs correctly.(I need to call it when the web browser is loaded completely but my web browser is defined in user control)

Comment: `list.OuterHTML+= Value;` doesn't makes sense. Maybe you want `list.OuterHTML= Value;`

Comment: @Musa:You are right,but I need the previous value.

Comment: Are you trying to add an `<option>` to the `<select>` or something?

Comment: @Musa:yes,that is what I am trying to do,but I need to do it when the webpage is loaded completely.I would be grateful if you tell me how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code assumes the document has finished loading, which isn't case during form load.
Wait until the DocumentCompleted event before accessing the document.